# When i change the width the height changes in itext

Tags: java, itext7

When i change the width the height changes in canvas.

```
ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.create("C:\\800px-Cubicpoly.png");
```

when i specify:

```
data.setWidth(100);
data.setHeight(180*2.834646f);
```

It turns out:
[image]

when i specify:

```
data.setWidth(600);
data.setHeight(180*2.834646f);
```

It turns out:
[image]

***I don’t touch the height, why does it change?***

```
doc.add(new Image(data).setPadding(0).setMargins(0,0,0,0));
```

original img(800x800):
[image]

Comment: The tag [tag:itext] predominantly is for itext 5.x (and before) but your code looks 7.x'ish. Please clarify. If it's indeed itext 7, please add the [tag:itext7] tag.

Comment: Furthermore, you appear to have changed something else, too. It appears like there used to be  two and a half boxes in front of paragraphs, now there is only half a box...

Comment: @mkl I only changed the height

Comment: But have a look at your images, the paragraph indentation changed, too. I think you should share a sscce.

Comment: @mkl I just cut out the content

Comment: Without an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) proving something else @Uladzimir's conjecture in his answer appears very plausible. You should follow up to it...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't attached the whole code, but I suppose that you use a default page size (A4). Taking into account that the width of the A4 page is 595 pt (considering margins, it would be even less) and you set the image width as 600pt, I presume that you get the following log message while processing your code: `com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer WARN Element does not fit current area.`

This lack of area is the reason why you get your image processed in a unexpected way. Just to make you sure, please change the size of the document to a bigger one (for instance, A3) and see that everything is processed as expected.

So what does iText normally do when it's not possible to process an image on a set area? iText **autoscales** it, trying to take as much place as possible, but to retain the image's proportions. You said that the image's height is changing: but that's the same for the width as well.

Comment: @ruslan If iText doesn't autoscale down the image, it doesn't fit into the available space (limited left and right by the page margins) and it cannot be added to the document subject to iText automatic layout'ing. (You can still add it using absolute, independent positioning...) One thing you might want to try, though: use negative left and right image padding or margin values...

Comment: The answer depends on how you want iText to process images that cannot fix the area